# Convert time from British to American format

Tags: sql, t-sql, date, datetime, sql-server-2005

I have the below code which is failing at the 'CAST('10-10-2014' AS DATETIME)', please can someone assist?

```
SELECT Sum(poval)
FROM   iesa_dwhs.dbo.vw_an_purch_bkb_010_sources vw_AN_Purch_BKB_010_Sources
WHERE  Upper(plant) = Upper(('0LH0'))
       AND dt BETWEEN Cast('10-10-2014' AS DATETIME) AND Getdate() - 7
       AND Upper(matcat) = 'CODED'
```

Comment: can you tell us if it's `DD-MM-YYYY`  or `MM-DD-YYYY`?

Comment: Since you're using a hard-coded value anyway, why not just write `AND dt BETWEEN '2014-10-10 00:00:00' AND Getdate() - 7`, you don't need to `cast` anything if you provide it as YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS.

Comment: If you requirement is to consider only date (ignore time part) then use the cast around getdate() function also (eg. AND dt BETWEEN Cast('10-10-2014' AS DATE) AND CAST(GETDATE() -7 as date)

Comment: Hi unfortunately the date must be hardcoded. The data is taken straight from excel VBA and the original format is 13/10/2014.

Comment: If you're already changing the format (you said your Excel VBA uses `mm/dd/yyyy` and your question is showing either `mm-dd-yyyy` or `dd-mm-yyyy`) then why can't you change the value to `yyyy-mm-dd` which I believe would be accepted in either culture?

Comment: Oh, 13/10/2014 fails.  Why did you put 10-10-2014 in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Read the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). Be explicit about your conversion:

```
select british_style_datetime = convert(datetime, '23-10-2015 20:15:10.123' , 103 )
```

If you are not explicit about it, the conversion will be done per the configured settings for the SQL Server instance in question. And if the date/time string is non-ambigous, the conversion is likely to fail, with something like this:

```
select convert(datetime, '23-10-2015' )
```

producing (on my SQL Server):

```
Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type
resulted in an out-of-range value.
```

And if the conversion is ambiguous, the operation will probably succeed, but you're likely to get an incorrect value, with something like

```
select convert(datetime, '11-10-2015' )
```

producing (on my SQL Server):

```
2015-11-10 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Thank you  '= convert(datetime, '23-10-2015 20:15:10.123' , 103 ) ' works well

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure dt it a datetime?

The safe bet is yyyy-mm-dd as that only has one mm dd format

All this works for me

```
select Cast('10-10-2014' AS DATETIME) 
select Cast('2014-10-10' AS DATETIME)
select GETDATE() 
select GETDATE() - 7 

select 'yes'
where Cast('2014-10-15' AS DATETIME)  between Cast('2014-10-10' AS DATETIME) AND Getdate() - 7 

select 'yes'
where Cast('10-12-2014' AS DATETIME)  between Cast('10-10-2014' AS DATETIME) AND (Getdate() - 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server 2014 or newer, you can use the [DATEFROMPARTS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx) function.  Then you won't need to worry about the format.

Comment: Hi, I should have specified, I'm using 2005

Comment: @DeadZone...what do you mean: if you use `datefromparts()`, you've still got to parse the date/time string into its constituent parts (and then convert them to integer values).